# Css ( styled-components ) issue with dropdown

Tags: css, styled-components

I'm developing a dropdown, where you click or focus the input, a white container should display at the bottom of the input, the problem is that, the focus is not working and i don't know why ( i hate css :/ )

So this is the code

This is the structure

```
<NavbartPart1SearchBar>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar en Facebook" maxLength={100} />
        {/* Dropdown */}
        <NavbarPart1Dropdown> </NavbarPart1Dropdown>
      </NavbartPart1SearchBar>
```

```
export const NavbarPart1Dropdown = styles.div`
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

    width: 100%;
    height: 20vh;
    background: white;

    
`;

export const NavbartPart1SearchBar = styles.div`

position: relative;

input{
    width: 255px;
    font-size: 1.53rem;
    font-weight: 300;

    padding: 1.23rem 1.75rem;
    border-radius: 2.1rem;

    background: #F0F2F5;

    &:focus ${NavbarPart1Dropdown} {
      display: flex;
    }

}


`;
```

So as you can see, input has a focus event, when i focus on it, i add display flex to the other container, but it won't work, do you see any problems with my code?

Know let me show you how it should look

[image]

Do you see the black part ? i want that to appear when focus, so, if you can help me, you're cool !

Answer (score 1):

You can select the next sibling element with `+` in CSS. So the following should work:

```
input:focus + ${NavbarPart1Dropdown} { display: block; }
```

Comment: Thanks for yout answer !